# Can't get splash screen icon on Android Chrome PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I've created a PWA that installs correctly, with a launcher icon. I want a different image for the splash screen, so I've included 192px and 512px png's, both 128dpi and listed them both in manifest.json - however, my splash screen still displays the launcher icons (which I have provided in 36, 48, 72, 96, 128, 144 px versions)

How do I ensure the correct image gets used for splash screen vs launcher icon?

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "short_name": "app",
  "name": "app",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-36-36.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-48-48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-72-72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-96-96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-128-128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-144-144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/android-launchericon-192-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/pwa/splash-512-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#splash-screen-icons), as you have already known, Chrome will choose the icon that closely matches the `128dp` icon for that device.

Please take note that `dp` (Density-independent Pixels) is different from `dpi` (Dots Per Inch). Simply put, `128dpi` is not necessarily equal to `128dp`, which is most likely the problem in your case.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8478997) explains the difference between the two well.

> For example, on a `160dpi` screen, `1dp == 1px == 1/160in`, but on a
>   `240dpi` screen, `1dp == 1.5px`. So no, `1dp != 1px`. There is exactly one
>   case when `1dp == 1px`, and that's on a `160dpi` screen. Physical
>   measurement units like inches should never be part of your design—that
>   is, unless you're making a ruler.
>
> A simple formula for determining how many pixels `1dp` works out to is
>   `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`.

Based on this simple formula, your `192px, 128dpi` image has `240dp`, while your `512px, 128dpi` image has `640dp`. Assuming your other images all have `128dpi` as well, then Chrome is most likely picking your `96px` image due to it having the closest `dp` to `128dp`.

In conclusion, for your `192px` or `512px` images to have `128dp`, they need to have `160dpi`.

Comment: Wow, amazing answer - thanks so much! I'll check it works tomorrow and will vote once confirmed.

Comment: So a further question for @Jacque - if my PWA will be deployed to all sorts of phones with all sorts of dpi screen densities, how do I control what images get used for splash screens, and what images get used for launcher icons?

Comment: As far as I know, Chrome only looks at your images' `dp` and not the device's.

Comment: My calcs say my 192px must have dpi of 240 to get 128dp, and my 512px must have dpi of 640?

Comment: Lol no matter what I do, it always selects my 96px image for the splash screen - I changed its dpi to 240 which should put its dp way out of range (64) but still the PWA chooses that for the splash screen.

Comment: Interestingly, when I add to HomeScreen on my windows laptop, it uses the other image (192px, or 512px) as the launcher icon - this seems to suggest that different screen densities use different images, making it almost impossible to separate launcher icons and splash icons...

Comment: Having defined 512px, 256px, and 192px images in manifest.json and having a device display density factor of 2x i.e. 720px = 360dp (xhdpi) Chrome elected to use the 192px image (interesting because documentation states nearest to 128dp will be selected which is 256px on the device which is *NOT* the one Chrome uses)

Either way, the image on the splash screen is still *tiny*